# Testing bluetooth from within iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have followed the instructions on [Technical Note TN2295](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html) to enable testing bluetooth within the iOS Simulator, which includes buying a separate Bluetooth 4 dongle. However, within the Simulator when I go to the iOS Bluetooth settings, I can turn bluetooth on, but it never discovers any other bluetooth device (yes, those devices are discoverable).

I have tried the following to narrow things down:

- I can pair the MacBook with the bluetooth device (Pebble watch), but it is not clear if I am doing so  with the in-built bluetooth, or the bluetooth dongle.
- I can plug the dongle into a Windows PC that doesn't have bluetooth, and then pair it to the Pebble watch. This tells me the dongle is working.

Other questions on SO relate to not being able to turn bluetooth on in the Simulator, but I am getting past this point. Can anybody help with the next step?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [ReadMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9) from ExternalAcccessory (non-LE bluetooth) framework's demo, there's no support to connect to real accessories through [simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/iOS_Simulator_Guide.pdf).
Also, the technical note you mentioned applies only to the CoreBluetooth framework (LE bluetooth).

So you can only connect to Low-energy (Bluetooth 4.0) devices from your iOS simulator.

As far as i know, Pebble watch is using both Bluetooth 2.1 and Bluetooth 4.0 though. In this case, you can try connecting to it using CoreBluetooth framework.